Neutrino Free Streaming Time (The very early universe)
Taking the below plot as a rough approximation on how comoving scales evolve as a function of time with some important epochs marked

Consider primordial gravitational waves (PGW) from inflation; once tensor modes cross the horizon exit they will be frozen on super-horizon scales. And at the horizon re-entry, they will have the same amplitude as they had at the horizon exit.
1) After the re-entry, these modes will be red-shifted due to the expansion of the universe so PGW amplitude will be suppressed.
However there can be additional suppressions e.g.
2) Anisotropic stress due to free streaming neutrinos can cause the tensor modes to be damped. Anisotropic stress from neutrinos will play a role until neutrinos become non-relativistic (NR)

In dark energy era, this effect will be negligible since accelerated expansion of the universe will be the dominant suppression and neutrinos are NR

In matter era, this effect will be slightly negligible since anisotropic stress due to neutrinos $\Pi_k \propto f_{\nu}$ where $f_{\nu}$ is the fraction of energy density of neutrinos to overall energy density diminishes

In radiation era this effect is considerable


Before neutrino decoupling, while they are still relativistic, neutrinos are strongly interacting with the rest of the universe while once they decoupled (relativistic), they start free-streaming and they can induce anisotropic stress.
Once they decouple at $1$ MeV, they will be only NR at $T_{\nu} \approx m_{\nu}$, if we call the time they spend free-streaming $\Delta t_{standard}$
My question is:

If they decoupled earlier than $1$ second (above $1$ MeV), their temperature will be higher at the decoupling, however they will no longer be in thermal equilibrium hence their temperature will drop faster therefore they will become non-relativistic sooner. Would this time interval let's call $\Delta t_{new}$ be larger/smaller than $\Delta t_{standard}$?

